# How to disable menu popup animation

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, styles, popupmenu

I use following code to create menu, when i click button, it show popup animation, how to disable it?

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_create_menu_in_code);

    View b = findViewById(R.id.b);
    final PopupMenu m = new PopupMenu(this, b);
    m.getMenu().add(0, 1, 0, "Create");
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popup animation can be changed from your style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:popupAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="NoPopupAnimation" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

And:

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.NoPopupAnimation);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, view, Gravity.END);
```

Using this way you don't need to change the style for the whole activity. For example in my case, Popup animation has issue on Huawei devices. So I just need to disable animation for Huawei only. This is how I make it:

```
Context wrapper = this;
if ("huawei".equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
    wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.NoPopupAnimation);
}
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, view, Gravity.END);
```